# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal in Python

Tags: python-3.x

In the following code, I am trying to get elements that can be trained on SpaCy NER Model (in the 9th line of code).

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

train_data_list = []

for i in range(len(train_data)):
    a = re.search(train_data.subtext[i], train_data.text[i])
    if a is not None:
        element = '("' +train_data.text[i] + '"' + ', {"entities": [(' + 
        str(a.start()) + ',' + str(a.end()) + ',"SKILL")]})'
        train_data_list.append(literal_eval(element))
```

But I am encountering the following error

```
 SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look at the *text value* of `element` as the time of `literal_eval`. Fix the code to ensue it is valid: I suspect it might be .. 'funky'.

Comment: The text value of train_data consists of continous text. I am encountering problem only in few cases. (I mean while processing certain text values only.)

Comment: Exactly! Because *some* of those values result in a string that cannot be parsed with `literal_eval`. If a *specific example* is identified the problem should be 'clear'. Include the *specific* value of `element` in such failing cases in the question, so that proper solutions can be suggested.

Comment: The example when the code fails is when the text value is as follows.
`\ncreate asset tracking database used for gain/loss profits, facility overhead, and finance research, including\nassisting in the implementation of sap business one. email correspondence, and proposal correspondence (both the\ncreation and assessment of). contract negotiations from customer/client to third party vendors and facilities.\nbuilt solid, transparent client /vendor relationships, with high client/vendor retention.`

Even in the case where the text has `"` It worked fine.

Comment: That's not the *full text* of `element`, which would be something like `("...", {"entities": [(...,"SKILL")]})` were the ...'s are "some data". (I was wrong on the `"` bit - that would be a different error if manifested ^_^.)

Comment: The element ideally looks like this.

`("airtran airlines, sun country airlines, wifi upgrades and maintenance on crj, 7 and 900,b757", {"entities": [(36,39,"SKILL")]})`

Comment: Right: so which is the first value of `element` (as an example case) that throws the error? Consider using a try-catch around `literal_eval` with a `repr` to log the suspect data (using `repr` will also display things like unexpected 'whitespace' characters).

Comment: The error appears while processing the following text value.
`\ncreate asset tracking database used for gain/loss profits, facility overhead, and finance research, including\nassisting in the implementation of sap business one. email correspondence, and proposal correspondence (both the\ncreation and assessment of). contract negotiations from customer/client to third party vendors and facilities.\nbuilt solid, transparent client /vendor relationships, with high client/vendor retention.`
When the code fails I will not be able to get _element_ value.

Comment: I've included an "answer" that shows how to obtain the failing `element` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot split a long line into multiple lines hitting enter. Either change your `element=` line to a single line like this

```
element = '("' +train_data.text[i] + '"' + ', {"entities": [(' + str(a.start()) + ',' + str(a.end()) + ',"SKILL")]})'
```

or add a `\` at the end of the line

```
element = '("' +train_data.text[i] + '"' + ', {"entities": [(' + \
        str(a.start()) + ',' + str(a.end()) + ',"SKILL")]})'
```

Comment: The code I am writing in my notebook is actually in on one line.

Comment: Are you copying your code somewhere from the notebook to your local IDLE?

Comment: No, I am running in the notebook itself.

Comment: I am having no problem by pasting that line into my jupyter notebook. Double check the line that you have in your notebook.

Answer (score 0):

One (or more) of the `element` *strings* supplied to `literal_eval` cannot be parsed by `literal_eval`.. That is, the program syntax is valid (or else the program would fail without running anything!), and it is one or more of the `element` *values* supplied to `literal_eval` is *not* valid Python!

The first step is to identify some 'invalid' values, eg.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

train_data_list = []

for i in range(len(train_data)):
    a = re.search(train_data.subtext[i], train_data.text[i])
    if a is not None:
        element = '("' +train_data.text[i] + '"' + ', {"entities": [(' + str(a.start()) + ',' + str(a.end()) + ',"SKILL")]})'
        try:
            data = literal_eval(element)
            train_data_list.append(data)
        except:
            print("Failed to parse element as a Python literal!")
            print(">>")
            print(repr(element))
            print("<<")
```

If the above "runs" (fsvo. "runs") then the proposed hypothesis holds the non-relevant answers can be ignored ;-)

Anyway, the solution is to *not* use `literal_eval` at all. Instead, create an object directly:

```
for i in range(len(train_data)):
    a = re.search(train_data.subtext[i], train_data.text[i])
    if a is not None:
        # might be a bit off.. YMMV.
        data = (train_data.text[i],
                {"entities": [(str(a.start()), str(a.end()), "SKILL")]})
        train_data_list.append(data)
```

Now, if *values* of `train_data.text[i]` contain a `\n` - that is, the literal two-character '\' and 'n' escape sequence - there may be additional work required to turn those into newline *characters* .. but one step at a time. And no step should be backward! :D